# Sceneview freezes when present web view controller

Tags: ios, scenekit, arkit, sceneview

I'm using `Safari Services kit` to present a web view when an `SCNode` is clicked. However, when I go back from the `safariVC` to my VC with the `sceneView`, the `sceneView` is frozen even though I restart the session by re-running the session.

I read on this [website](https://forum.omz-software.com/topic/1274/sceneview-is-frozen-when-presenting-another-ui-view/2) that presenting another VC kills the scene view thread and I would just like confirmation. Basically I want to know whether it is possible to present another VC and be able to go back to the `sceneView` and "resume" the `scenView`

*Note:*

- VC = ViewController

### Code

*How I present my safari web VC*

```
func presentWebView(){
    if let url = URL(string: "https://www.amazon.com/"){
        let safariVC = SFSafariViewController(url: url)
        self.present(safariVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

*How I restart my session*

```
if let worldSessionConfig = sessionConfig as? ARWorldTrackingSessionConfiguration {
    worldSessionConfig.planeDetection = .horizontal
    session.run(worldSessionConfig, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sceneView.session.pause()` when you present safariVC and then use `sceneView.session.run` to restart session when safariVC is dismissed.